# How to input different information to a modal?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to input information via 'info' to change the value of the modal. Currently all that is happening is the modal opens with blank space, any ideas on how to fix this?
Many thanks!

I'm trying to input information via 'info' to change the value of the modal. Currently all that is happening is the modal opens with blank space, any ideas on how to fix this?
Many thanks!

```
const MemberComponent = ({img, name=" ", position=" "}) => {

  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false)

  const openModal = () => {
    setShowModal(prev => !prev)
  }

  return(
    <Item>
      <ImageContainer>
        <img onClick={openModal} width={500} height={400}  src={img} alt={name}/>
        <Modal showModal={showModal} setShowModal={setShowModal} />
      </ImageContainer>
      <Name>{name}</Name>
      <Position>{position}</Position>
    </Item>
  )
}

const Modal = ({showModal, setShowModal, info=" "}) => {
  
  return (
  <>
      {showModal ? <Name>{info}</Name> : null}
  </>
  )
}

const Team = () => {
  return (
    <Section id="team">
    <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
    <ConfettiComponent  /> </Suspense>
      <Title>Team</Title>
      <Container>
        <MemberComponent img={img1}  name="Micky" position="Founder" info="This is a test" />
        <MemberComponent img={img2}  name="Dr. Young" position="Co-Founder" info="This information needs to be passed in"/>
        <MemberComponent img={img3}  name="Alexander Torres" position="Director" />
        <MemberComponent img={img4}  name="Stonk" position="manager" />
        <MemberComponent img={img5}  name="VOID4" position="artist" />
        <MemberComponent img={img6}  name="VOID5" position="social media manager" />
        <MemberComponent img={img7}  name="VOID6" position="Specialist" />
        <MemberComponent img={img8}  name="VOID7" position="Developer" />
        <MemberComponent img={img9}  name="VOID8" position="Graphic Designer" />
      </Container>
    </Section>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like you are passing in info in the JSX here `<MemberComponent img={img1}  name="Micky" position="Founder" info="This is a test" />`

But not accessing it in the component here `const MemberComponent = ({img, name=" ", position=" "}) => {`

after properly accessing it in the above, pass it to Modal properly here `<Modal showModal={showModal} setShowModal={setShowModal} />`